# Limiting class and class properties

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to limit a class so only 1 property can hold value while rest will have to be null. Or do I have just have to handle it by assigning all others to null when any is set?

Is there any more viable way of approaching this?

Comment: You can write your own custom validator and use IValidateableObject interface

Comment: That sounds nice, what do you think about custom attribute for validation? Could work nicely as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty you're having is that you're trying to use a conjunction (`AND`) to express a disjunction (`OR`).

When you have a class with a bunch of properties like

```
class Foo
{
    public Something        Property1 { get; set; }
    public SomethingElse    Property2 { get; set; }
    public Whatever         Property3 { get; set; }

}
```

You're saying that Foo is:

`Something` **AND** `SomethingElse` **AND** `Whatever`.

But, what you really want to say is that Foo is:

`Something` **OR** `SomethingElse` **OR** `Whatever`.

As [David Arno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7122/david-arno) mentioned in his answer, ML languages like F# have a compact way of expressing this idea using discriminated unions. But, the larger concept is that of a *[sum type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_type)*, which is the way to express the notion of disjunction (i.e. the logical `OR`) in the type system. C# can also easily express sum types, albeit with a bit more typing than F# (no pun intended).

```
public class Foo
{
    public Bar Property { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Bar
{
    public class Something : Bar
    {

    }

    public class SomethingElse : Bar
    {

    }

    public class Whatever: Bar
    {

    }
}
```

Now we have what you want: Objects of type `Foo` are either a `Something` **or** `SomethingElse` **or** `Whatever`, but they can only be one of those things at any given time.

Comment: I really like this approach :D

Answer (score 4):

There is no way built in to C# to do this. What you are describing is handled via [discriminated unions in F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233226.aspx), but C# doesn't have such types. You could write your own union class to offer such behaviour though.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement it like this on a class

```
public class OneProp
{
  private string val1;
  public string Value1 { get { return val1; } };

  private string val2;
  public string Value2 { get { return val2; } };

  public void SetValue(string propName, string propValue)
  {
   // null all values here
   val1 = null;
   val2 = null;

    switch(propName)
    {
      case "Value1":
      val1 = propValue;
      break;

      case "Value2":
      val1 = propValue;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

then create an instance of it;

```
OneProp val = new OneProp();
val.SetValue("name", "value");
```

You can also do it in the constructor.